# Modal reload after ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone help me with this code?
I'm trying to reload a modal to use in another database query
I have success and i want to reload the modal to use in anothe record

```
if(result === 'success'){
  $("#editarModalOcup").modal('hide');
  $('#success .modal-body').html('Informação: ' + data.message);
  $('#success').modal('show');
  $('#success').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    /*$('#editarModalOcup').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
     });
     $("#editarModalOcup").modal('show');*/
  });
}
```

But this code doesn't work and the button get the forbidden signal and i can't use it...any help?

Thanks

UPDATE
Html modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editarModalOcup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-header-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Editar Ocupação de Sala</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
            <form id="editarOcupacao" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_ocupacao" id="edit_ocupacao">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_dia" id="edit_dia">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_tempo" id="edit_tempo">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Sala:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="edit_sala_nome" id="edit_sala_nome" disabled="true">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i></span>
                        <select name="id_turma" class="form-control">
                            <?php echo $optionTurma ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="editarOcup" id="editarOcup" value="editarOcup">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Atualizar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to provide some of the HTML markup as well

Comment: check update please

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem
Using formvalidation do:

```
 $('#modal').show().formValidation('resetForm');
```